# Printing a Document

Tags: c#, printing

I want to print my `TextBox` and here is my code:

```
private void MenuItemPrint()
{
        if (FileName != "")
        {
            PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
            document.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = FileName;
            document.Print();
        }
}
```

and it doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: You should tell in what way it doesn't work.

Comment: @Melody: Which error you are getting?

Comment: notting happen when i click for print

Comment: Is your FileName is TextBox Control?

Comment: what can i do instd of that for printing my textbox?

Comment: @MelodyHajian: what is Exactly FileName in your code? is it a TextBox Control Name or is it a String?

Comment: You forgot to tell your document what to print (to draw the string)

Comment: @MelodyHajian:could you please show us the FileName contents?

Comment: Using PrintDocument you must register for event PrintPage and inside implement code for printing. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DanielAbouChleih String

Comment: What do you want to tell us with `String`???

Comment: @DanielAbouChleih: i think OP wants to print the String entered in some TextBox , please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @Sudhakar: Think so too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This:

```
private void MenuItemPrint()
{
   if (!FileName.Trim().Equals(""))
   {                        
     using(PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument())
     {
        using(PrintDialog printDialog=new PrintDialog())
        {
          if(printDialog.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.Yes)
          {
          pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);                        
          pd.Print();
          }
         }
      }
    }
 }
private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
  ev.Graphics.DrawString(FileName, new Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Black,
                       ev.MarginBounds.Left, 0, new StringFormat());
 }
```

Comment: is there any shorter code for that? i simply want to print the content of my textbox..

Comment: i think there is no shorter code than this IMO. because you have to write the statements to initialise printDocument ,register the PrintPage Event and finally printing string using drawstring.

Comment: actually Trim() function will remove the leading and trailing spaces in a textbox generally which we can not see.if we don't trim the values before comparing then if("    "=="") evaluates to false.

Comment: are you able to print now?

Answer (score 4):

You can use following code to print the content of a textbox with the selected printer:

```
private void PrintTextBoxContent()
{
    #region Printer Selection
    PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
    #endregion

    #region Create Document
    PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
    printDoc.DocumentName = "Print Document";
    printDoc.PrintPage += printDoc_PrintPage;
    printDlg.Document = printDoc;
    #endregion

    if(printDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
       printDoc.Print();
}

void printDoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(this.textBox1.Text, this.textBox1.Font, Brushes.Black, 10, 25);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just try with following code

```
private void MenuItemPrint()
 {
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileName.Trim())
   {
    PrintDialog printdg = new PrintDialog();

    if (printdg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.PrinterSettings = printdg.PrinterSettings;
        pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
        pd.Print();
        pd.Dispose();
     }
  }
}
private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
   e.Graphics.DrawString(FileName, new Font("Arial", 20), Brushes.Black, 10, 25);
}
```